# How can I find title of movies that have had no ratings or comments using mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

In this task, I have to get all the title which have had no ratings and comments. There are two tables one is "Movie" and "Ratings". In Movie table, there are several columns including the information about the movies and in Rating table there are ratings about movies and Movie_ID is the common column in these two tables.

I tried to get the work done:

```
db.movies.find({$or:[{"Comments":null},{"Rating":null}]}).pretty();
```

and this also

```
db.movies.find({[{$group:{_id:"$Movie_ID"}}]},{$or:[{"Comments":null},{"Rating":null}]}
```

But this is not working. Here is the excel [sheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bqDDwcNWI0UT53qbHTeeqUe_d_T3J_q2).

Please help if any one can help. Thankyou.

Comment: you should use `$exists` of mongodb
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: I will not  get the result which i want because this problem may be done using lookup and aggregate.May be

Comment: Can you post your sample data in json, to test a query?